# HTML Posting Data in Android

Tags: java, android, html, post

So, I've made a HTML page that contains **two radio buttons** named **on** **and** off as below:

```
<input type="radio" name="args" value="on">Turn the LED on.
<input type="radio" name="args" value="off">Turn the LED off.
```

And, below those two buttons is a **submit button** whose code is:

```
<input type="submit" value="Do it!">
```

This simple setup is inside a **form**, whose code is:

```
<form action="https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/your-device-ID-goes-here/led?access_token=your-access-token-goes-here" method="POST">
```

Please **ignore the URL** I put in there.

So, what this does is,
when I select the Radio Button corresponding to ON, and hit submit(Named as : do it!), it turns on an LED on my Particle Photon.

So what I want to do is, to make an Android app as follows:

1) Create **two buttons** one for ON and one for OFF

(I can create them in XML using **android studio** and I know the JAVA part, but I do not know how to **combine the HTML and JAVA** Part)

2) When any of the buttons is pressed, the corresponding command should be passed to the url, and on doing so, the Particle Photon Device will act accordingly.

Note that I am using **POST in HTML**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can achieve the same result implementing the Web page directly in your board (like Arduino and so on).

If you want to use an Android app you shouldn't use HTML page, but you should develop an app that sends HTML post (or something like it) to the server.
In this case, i suggest using JSON format.
In this [simple guide](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/06/internet-of-things-with-android-and-arduino.html) I wrote you find the details how to implement an app that turns on and off a remote led connected to Arduino.
It is more or less what you are looking for.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but, I need to POST the value "on" to the given url(which acts as a cloud server between my phone and the Particle Photon device) as you can see in the HTML code of the Radio Button, it holds a value, which is either on or off